# Number of arguments in function

Tags: scheme, gambit

Let's say I have a structure "phonenumber".

```
(define-structure phonenumber country area prefix line)
```

This will give me a function (make-phonenumber).  I would like to get the number of arguments that make-phonenumber takes. The answer is 4.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? There might be another way.

Comment: I have a list that I want to turn into a Record using (apply).  The list may have an incorrect number of fields, and if so I will correct the list before applying.

Comment: I could simply have a value for the number of fields in the Record, however that would mean if I change the definition of the record, I would also have to update that value, which is undesirable (if it can be avoided).

Comment: Maybe I should just switch to racket.

Comment: @Matthew If you start with a list, is there a reason that you can't just use `length` to see how many elements you have?

Comment: The list is the data.  The data could be incorrect.  The structure would not be, it is written in code.  I'm going to just use tables instead though.

Answer (score 2):

See if your Scheme implementation offers the `procedure-arity` function.

Comment: Thanks Taymon.  I'm using Gambit but it appears it doesn't have that.